# Loading a default script everytime Powershell ISE is launched

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell ISE, I would like a default script (Template) to open every time I open Powershell ISE.

Is there a way this could be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put it in your [PowerShell ISE Profile](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/04/understanding-and-using-powershell-profiles.aspx).

To locate your personal ISE profile on the current machine, check the value of:

```
$profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost
```

To locate the default personal ISE profile on the current machine, check the value of:

```
$profile.AllUsersCurrentHost
```